# Screen Detecting and re-sizing stuff

Tags: jquery, css

I have a main menu and a game for the app I am developing, the problem is that everything is made and margined/sized for the iphone/ipod 4 display.

My question is how can I detect what device the user is playing on using jQuery, and what would be the best way to change the margins, as you can see in the fiddle I have below that the buttons have a margin to move it left, if I were to change the width of that for lets say Iphone six display it would not be centered it would be to the left of were I want it.

Below is some code and a javascript/jQuery fiddle, with HTML and CSS.

```
width: 320px;
height: 480px;
```

That is what i currently have as far as the screen width's go.
and the margin-lefts here.

```
margin-left: 90px;
```

Here is a link! ***[jSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pL1t5948/)***.

Comment: FYI; you don't need JavaScript, you can use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery, you can detect the width of a device like this:

```
var isMobile = false;
var width = $(window).width();
if (width <= 350) {
      isMobile = true;
}
```

Or, if you want to try and detect the device:

```
var isIDevice = (/iphone|ipad/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));
```

The first example simply detects the width of the screen. If it's below or equal to 350px, it is probably save to say that you deal with a mobile device (in portrait mode). For portrait and landscape mode use 480px instead.

The second example detects the device. If it's an iphone or ipad, 'isIDevice' will be true. However, I do not suggest you use that one, it's called browser sniffing and in my experience it is not always accurate.

The best way to handle different screens are media queries. Using CSS, you can detect the screen width/height and style your page accordingly.

Let's say, you need to detect the width of an IPhone4 and adjust your elements according to that width. You do it like that:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  body {
    background: #ccc;
  }
}
```

The above example is a media query. If I translate this to human language, it goes something like that:

"If it is a screen (not printer or whatever) **AND** if the screen is smaller or equal to 320px **THEN** use this CSS"

Above this media query you can define the background to be black for example:

```
  body {
    background: black;
  }

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  body {
    background: #ccc;
  }
}
```

Now, if the screen is wider than 320px, the background will be black. And if the screen is equal to or smaller than 320px, the below CSS will become active and because it is defined after the first CSS (black background), it will take over thus making the background gray.

You can detect much more, than just the width. With media queries you can detect the width/height of the screen, the pixel ratio, the device orientation,...

There are almost infinite possibilities if you use media queries, using JavaScript for conditional styling makes sense only in very specific scenarios. If you can, use media queries instead of JavaScript.

Comment: For the if(width <= 350){...} could i use like <= 320px. because i know that if the width is greater than 320 than it could be an iphone 6,

Comment: Also, would you do 
if(isMobile) {
  what here, maybe .css or what
}

Comment: Yes, you can use the width you want to detect. 320px, 350px whatever width you need to detect. And I strongly suggest you do not use javascript for conditional styling. CSS media queries are the way to go. I'll extend my answer to explain about media queries

Comment: The only problem I have is that is it will double the 2k lines of css i have already you know? It may cause lots of lag and im trying to stay away from that.

Comment: 2K lines of CSS should not cause any lag. Every day I am working on projects with 10k or even 20k lines of CSS and we don't detect any problems. If you minify your CSS, it will load much faster. Also, if you need a way to manage all that CSS, have a look at SCSS and the Compass framework. It's amazing :)

Comment: Ok cool, also I have a question, is there a way to do this, in jQuery 
if(array.css.margin-left > 0)

Comment: As far as I know, that's not possible in CSS. For this you will still need JavaScript. In jQuery you can do this like this: if($('#element').css("marginLeft") > 0){ //do stuff }. If you want to style an element conditionally, the best way to do it assign it a class: if($('#element').css("marginLeft") > 0){ $('#elementToStyle').addClass('specificClass'); }. Now you just style that class in CSS. This is the way this stuff is usually handled.

Comment: Would this be right, I have an array         
var allObj = [$("[id^='B'][id$='Obj']"),$("[id^='A'][id$='Obj']"), $("[id^='C'][id$='Obj']"),$("[id^='D'][id$='Obj']")];
and I want to take that whole array and add 55px to it, how could that be accomplished.

Comment: You would have to add the 55px to each element in array separately: $.each(allObj,function(index,value){ value.css("marginLeft", value.css("marginLeft")+55); }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69153/discussion-between-nick-and-itd).